# Spotfire trimmed mean in bar plot

Tags: spotfire

I have a bar plot in Spotfire that shows the mean of a variable per group. Instead of the mean I would like to use the trimmed mean to make it more robust to outliers. I'm new to Spotfire, how do I do that? Trimmed mean means to order your values, cut off the first and last x% and take the mean over the remainder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit this using `Percentile()`. You can use this in your expression or insert a calculated column. Here is the calculated column example so you can see what's limited.

On the tool bar, Insert > Calculated Column > `If([ValueColumn]>=Percentile([ValueColumn],10),True,False) as [InRange]`

This will set a `TRUE BOOLEAN` value to each row if it is >= 10%, and a `FALSE` if it is not. Instead of hard coding 10 you can use a property control if you'd like. Then, you can reference this column in your chart like:

`If([InRange] = TRUE,Avg([ValueColumn])) as [LimitedMean]`

I've attached an image to show the results. If this doesn't work, you can sort your data using `Rank(), DenseRank(), and RankReal()` and then limit this way.

Lastly, you can do all of this "in line" in your bar chart like so:

`If([ValueColumn]>=Percentile([ValueColumn],10),Avg([ValueColumn]))`

[image: Result & Test Data]